# Суммарный размер файлов в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, foreach, filesize

Имеется массив:

```
$files = array("folder/file1.txt", "folder/file2.txt");
```

С помощью функции *filesize* необходимо найти общую сумму размеров всех файлов в массиве.

Подозреваю, что необходимо подключить конструкцию *foreach*, но никак не могу понять как это реализовать.

Думаю, что можно сделать примерно так:

```
$files = array("folder/file1.txt", "folder/file2.txt");
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $filesize = filesize($file[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Но никак не могу его довести до ума.

Comment: `$filesize = filesize($file[$i]);` => `$filesize += filesize($file[$i]);` `$i++` => ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = array("folder/file1.txt", "folder/file2.txt");
$sum = 0;
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    $sum+=filesize($file);
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

для коллекции

```
$result = array_sum(array_map('filesize', $files));
```

Comment: Пожалуй, самый изящный метод из предложенных )